# Understanding position in while loop with if statement

Tags: python

This is the code that I'm analyzing:

```
x = 5

while x > 0:
    x -= 1
    if x == 5:
        print("Friendly Fires")
    print("Hello")
```

The output for this is "hello" 5 times, as x is decremented by 1 at the start of the loop and never actually equals 5. But then why the 5th line of "hello"?

```
hello (4)
hello (3)
hello (2)
hello (1)
hello (???)
```

Zero is not bigger than zero, so that last line of "hello" is extremely confusing for me. Why is it there?

Comment: Well, do it step by step. The while-condition is checked at the beginning of each iteration. You'll figure it out.

Comment: The loop condition `while x > 0` is only checked at the **beginning** of each loop.  If the condition becomes false **inside** the loop body, that does not matter.  The loop keeps executing, then it will stop on the **next** iteration.

Comment: run it step by step. in a debugger or even with pen and paper

Comment: If you want a loop to execute an exact number of times, the pythonic way to do that is `for foo in range(N)`:

Comment: x value when it enter the while loops are `5,4,3,2,1` which are satisfing the exit condition

Comment: in your example output you’ve annotated each printed string  with the value of x at the end of each loop iteration but it’s the value of x at the beginning of each iteration that determine if another iteration will happen. And those values are 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 or five times through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> Python firstly checks the condition. If it is False, then the loop is terminated and control is passed to the next statement after the while loop body. If the condition is True, then the loop body is executed, and then the condition is checked again. This continues while the condition is True. Once the condition becomes False, the loop terminates and control is passed to the next statement after the loop.

The `while` loop is first checking the value of x and then decreasing one from its value. So when it enters the while the last time the value of `x` is `1` (`5->4->3->2->1`, overall 5 times). You can read [here](https://snakify.org/en/lessons/while_loop/) more on how `while-loop` works.

Try following your code step-by-step and if it is still confusing you, try adding `print(x)` at the beginning of the `while-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

The validation of x > 0 is being done at the beginning of the iteration, so in the last one the value is 1 so it runs, and just after the validation is going to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your output:

```
hello (5)
hello (4)
hello (3)
hello (2)
hello (1)
```

It will print "hello" 5 times, as you start from 5 and go down to 0. It means the loop will check condition for 6 times and will iterate 5 times. For the first 5 times, it will print "hello" and for the last (6th) time, it will exit as condition will be false at that time.

Answer (score 0):

you are decrementing and printing the value after condition is checked, value has been 0 it has been printed and then condition is checked and loop is getting terminated, if you still want it to work your way, you can add more conditions as follows:

```
x=5
while x > 0:
    x=x-1
    if x==5:
        print("na")
    if(x!=0):
     print(x)
```

it will not print 0 and hello will be printed 4 times only.